# Is there a timeout for the networksetup command on macOS?

Tags: networking, osx, timeout, networksetup

I want to set a 1 second timeout for networksetup so the command does not take longer than 2 seconds at most.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to install the GNU tool `timeout` via `brew`:

```
$ brew install coreutils
```

You can see that `timeout` is part of this package:

```
$ brew list coreutils | grep timeout
/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.29/bin/gtimeout
/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.29/libexec/gnubin/timeout
/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.29/libexec/gnuman/man1/timeout.1
/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.29/share/man/man1/gtimeout.1
```

And then do this:

```
$ gtimeout 3 networksetup ....
```

#### Example

Here I'm doing a couple of extra things. I'm using `time` to show that the command exited after only 3 seconds, I guard the command with a `-k5` which will send a `SIGTERM` to the command if it goes past 5 secs.

```
$ time gtimeout -k5 3 sleep 10

real    0m3.005s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.003s
```